# @patch() doesn't produce expected behavior inside a decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm testing a view function in Flask that requires authentication. I want to remove the effect of authentication, and so I wrote a test like so:

```
@patch('auth0_.decode_jwt')
@patch('auth0_.get_token_auth_header')
def test_list_cards_endpoint(self, get_token_header, decode_jwt):
    decode_jwt.return_value = {
        'sub': 'auth0|123',
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer 123'
    }
    with current_app.test_request_context('/pay/list-cards', headers=headers):
        list_cards_endpoint()
```

Which works completely fine. Next I wanted to abstract the above code so I can re-use it all tests and so I turned it into a decorator:

```
def fake_auth0(f):
    @patch('auth0_.decode_jwt')
    @patch('auth0_.get_token_auth_header')

    def decorated(get_token_header, decode_jwt, *args, **kwargs):
        decode_jwt.return_value = {
            'sub': 'auth0|123',
        }
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 123'
        }
        with current_app.test_request_context('/pay/list-cards', headers=headers):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

And tried calling it:

```
@fake_auth0
def test_list_cards_endpoint(self):
    list_cards_endpoint()
```

And I'm getting an error back, the essence of which is that `@patch` statements are not working correctly. More specifically, they're not assigning the `return_value` to be what I want and instead I simply get `<MagicMock name='decode_jwt().__getitem__()' id='4540406656'>` as a return value for `decode_jwt`.

So it's like - the mock is working, but the return value is not.

Why might this be?

Comment: @gilch could you elaborate a little bit more? What are the implications of what you said? Any links you could share for me to go read?

Comment: Have you tried to use the context manager version of `patch` (e.g. `with patch(...) as get_token_header:`) instead of the decorators? I'm not sure if the decorators are correctly handled if inside another decorator.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen was leaving that as last resort - if nothing good comes out of this thread then will have to. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `self` parameter.

A function is not a method *during* a class definition when the decorator is applied. The `self` doesn't get bound until you access it as an attr with a dot, which triggers its [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

And `@patch` passes its object as the last argument, not the first, so using `*args` like that isn't going to work.

You could try not passing them as arguments at all:

```
def fake_auth0(f):
    get_token_header = MagicMock()
    decode_jwt = MagicMock()
    decode_jwt.return_value = {
        'sub': 'auth0|123',
    }

    @patch('auth0_.decode_jwt', decode_jwt)
    @patch('auth0_.get_token_auth_header', get_token_header)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):    
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 123'
        }
        with current_app.test_request_context('/pay/list-cards', headers=headers):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

Or alternatively, pull them out of `*args` before passing them on:

```
def fake_auth0(f):
    @patch('auth0_.decode_jwt', return_value={'sub': 'auth0|123'})
    @patch('auth0_.get_token_auth_header')
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        *args, get_token_auth_header, decode_jwt = args
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 123'
        }
        with current_app.test_request_context('/pay/list-cards', headers=headers):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion above by @gilch works to solve the original error but then I starter running into new ones, namely this:

```
AttributeError: Attributes cannot start with 'assert' or 'assret'
```

I gather this is because the decorator is defined outside the class - but defining it inside the class also comes with problems.

All in all I gave up on decorators and just wrote a context manager:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def auth0_faker(url):
    with patch('auth0_.decode_jwt') as mock_decode_jwt:
        with patch('auth0_.get_token_auth_header') as mock_auth_header:
            mock_decode_jwt.return_value = {
                'sub': 'auth0|123',
            }
            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer 123'
            }
            with current_app.test_request_context(url, headers=headers):
                yield
```

I find this much simpler to read and comprehend.